# Termination of process (error code -1073741571)

Tags: c++, codeblocks, eigen

So I am working on this simulation for which I am to write a code.
Initially, I used to get an error code 255 (0xff), which I thought could be because of adding Eigen to my code blocks. However, once I shifted my Eigen headers to the include folder of code blocks, I now get a new error, with the message being:-

> Process terminated with status -1073741571 (0 minute(s), 2 second(s))

I looked up this error and it says that it comes up when a bug causes stack overflow. I ran my debugger and got the message:-

> Registered new type: wxString
>
> Registered new type: STL String
>
> Registered new type: STL Vector
>
> Setting breakpoints Debugger name and version: GNU gdb (GDB) 7.6.1
>
> Child process PID: 13284
>
> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.

So I knew there is an error with one of my functions.
The following is my code (it's pretty big)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <random>
#include<math.h>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include<time.h>
#define pi atan(1) * 4       
using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;
int Poisson(int N)   
{
    int n=1;
    float x,y,k=0;
    do
    {
        x=(float)rand()/RAND_MAX;
        y = -log(x);
        k=k+y;
        n=n+1;     //n increases for each random number generated
    }
    while(k<N);  
    return n;
}
int sumrow(MatrixXd A,int row, int col_len)
{
    int sum=0;
    for(int i=0;i<col_len;i++)
    {
        sum=sum+A(row,i);
    }
    return sum;
}
void generate_D(MatrixXd A, int dim, MatrixXd D)
{
    for(int x=0;x<dim;x++)
    {
        for(int y=0;y<dim;y++)
        {
            if(x==y)
            {
                D(x,y)=1/sqrt(sumrow(A,x,y));
            }
            else
                { D(x,y) =0;  }
        }
    }
}
void sqmatrix_multiply(MatrixXd A,MatrixXd B,int dim, MatrixXd C)
{
    for(int i=0;i<dim;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<dim;j++)
        {
            for(int k=0;k<dim;k++)
            {
                C(i,j) = C(i,j) + (A(i,k)*B(k,j));
            }
        }
    }
}
void generate_B(MatrixXd A, int dim, MatrixXd B)
{
    MatrixXd D;
    MatrixXd C, inter1, inter2;
    generate_D(A,dim,D);
    sqmatrix_multiply(A,D,dim,inter1);
    sqmatrix_multiply(D,C,dim,inter2);
    for(int i=0;i<dim;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<dim;j++)
        {
            if(i==j)
            {
                    B(i,j) = 1 - inter2(i,j);
            }
            else
            {
                B(i,j) = 0 - inter2(i,j);
            }

        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    double X,Y,x,y,a,b,L[5000][5000],M[5000][5000];
    MatrixXd A, B;
    for(int i=0; i<5000;i++)
    {   L[i][i]=0;  M[i][i]=0;   }
    int N, I;
    cout<<"Enter your number and iterations";
    cin>>N>>I;
    int P[5000];
    for(int i=0; i<I; i++)
    {
        P[i]=Poisson(N);
    }
    for(int k=0; k<I; k++)
    {
        for (int j=0;j<P[k];j++)
        {
          A:
          X=(float)rand()/RAND_MAX;    
          Y=(float)rand()/RAND_MAX;
          x=sqrt(X);    
          y = 2*(pi)*Y;        
          a=x*cos(y);        
          b=x*sin(y);
          if((a*a)+(b*b)>1)     
          {
              goto A;
          }
          L[k][j] = a; M[k][j] = b;
        }
    }
    for(int a=0;a<I;a++)
    {
        for(int a1=0;a1<P[a];a1++)
        {
            for(int a2=0;a2<P[a];a2++)
            {
                if(a1==a2)
                {
                    A(a1,a2)=0;
                }
                else
                {
                    if(((L[a][a1]-L[a][a2])*(L[a][a1]-L[a][a2]))+((M[a][a1]-M[a][a2])*M[a][a1]-M[a][a2]) < 1)  //distance formula
                    {
                        A(a1,a2)=1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        A(a1,a2)=0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        generate_B(A,P[a],B);
        EigenSolver<MatrixXd> b(B,false);
        cout<<a+1<<" Eigen values are: \n "<<b.eigenvalues()<<"\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I tried out a few functions individually in different programs. The problem is not related to the Eigen headers since sumrow() worked perfectly fine.
However, the Poisson() function gave me the same error (-1073741571). I tried replacing do-while with a simple while but it didn't work.

Earlier, when I've used Poisson() separately, it used to work fine. But now, it is not working independently either.

Sorry for the long question, but I've been on it for over a week now and can't seem to figure it out. If you could tell me what possibly is wrong with my code, I would be really grateful.
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Which line causes the seg fault and what does the debugger say the call stack is at that point?

Comment: `double L[5000][5000],M[5000][5000];` probably too big for Automatic storage. 5000*5000*8 = 200 MB.

Comment: My "Call stack" pop-up is blank for some reason.

Comment: @user4581301 I tried a 100x100 matrix too, didn't help.

Comment: Won't change anything except the funny looks your code will get, but `goto A` and the label can be replaced with a while loop. "Too slow." you say? It's nothing compared to all of the trig functions math and floating point math.

Comment: `while(k<N);` can have precision problems. If `y` is small enough relative to `k`, `k=k+y;` will not change `k`. `y` will be lost to representation error. `k` will never reach `N`. This will be a different problem, mind you.

Comment: You've made sure that the user input for `I` is less than 5000?

Comment: @user4581301 I thought the biggest thing slowing down my program is the function which calls eigen values. Thanks for the advice! 
Unfortunately, the trigo functions are essential, as I need uniform random points.
How can I restrict a user input? I would still allocate as much memory to P.

Comment: To be honest the eigen call could be the big time-eater. I haven't profiled. My point is restricted to that one loop. `do { ... } while ((a*a)+(b*b)>1)` should be identical to the `goto` and not set off people's, "goto am BAAAADDDDD!" reflex. `if (I >= MAX_ARRAY_SIZE) { cout << "I too big" ; return -1; }` where `MAX_ARRAY_SIZE` is a constant used to size all of the related arrays in place of the current magic numbers or similar would allow you to remove bad input.

Comment: Apologies. Dropped an off by 1 bug in there.

Comment: I implemented the do-while instead of goto and restricted the input I, but my error still exists.

Comment: Yeah, that's just a code cleanliness thing. The problem is with the precision error in `while(k<N);`. This allows numbers that are out of the range of N to be returned from `Poisson` and then used as `P[K]` in `for (int j=0;j<P[k];j++)` allowing `j` to be out of range of `L` and `M`.

Comment: Any fix around that? 
The algorithm to simulate a Poisson random variable X with mean N is as follows:- 
A = min{n:(product from i to n)Ui < exp(-N)} and then take X=A-1, which translates to X = max{n:(summation from i to n) (-logUi) <= N} where Ui are uniform random variables in (0,1)

Comment: Use a higher precision floating point data type. Unfortunately this will only allow you to go so far before even the the new data type runs out of precision. Also consider what happens to `log` when `rand` returns 0. Do you have to write your own Poisson distribution? [If not use `std::poisson_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/poisson_distribution).

Comment: And don't forget that you have stack-killing big arrays to deal with as well. You have to fix both bugs.

Comment: I made the edit for log(0) error but that didn't help. 
I was encouraged to write my own, however I can try it out with poisson_distribution. 
What do you mean by higher precision floating point data type? I mean what do I have to change?

Comment: Do you suggest replacing L and M with matrices as well? I mean they would work the same way as my current 2D arrays are. That would leave me with just P as a large array

Comment: Just re-read a comment of yours earlier and spotted your big mistake. I'm ashamed I didn't put 2 and 2 together myself and spot it earlier. You are misusing Poisson. N is the mean, so you aren't returning numbers up to N that will fit into a nice N-sized array, you are returning numbers around N. If N is 100 you are returning numbers around 100, and a lot of these numbers will be over 100 and outside the bounds of a 100 element array.

Comment: There is a lot wrong with your code, first of all, you pass all your matrices by value, which means they will never change in the calling method. Second and more importantly: You access various matrices at indexes above the matrix size (if you had compiled without `-DNDEBUG` this should have been shown by an assertion -- this way it results in stack-corruption). If these hints are not sufficient, please read the "minimal" section of how to create a [mcve] again -- and make separate questions for every problem you are not able to solve yourself, preferably after looking for similar questions.

Comment: @user4581301 thanks a lot man!!!
Although using the in built poisson distribution didn't help, rewriting L and M as matrices without allocating any size made my program run.
Edit: Well not really, I encounter the 255 error after entering the number and number of iterations